# How to identify duplicates in data using SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, sql-query-store

Here's my scenario, I am querying a salesforce database and I have certain cases which have different case_id's but the content remains the same. i.e. the case description, case owner, case assigned team and all other related information are the same.

I can do a self join to identify such cases but my question to all you SQL gurus is - can this be done without using joins? The reason being, all these information is housed in different tables and makes things harder to do a self join?

Comment: Add a `QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY all columns but case_id) > 1`. Not really efficient, but returns what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

SELECT COUNT(CASE_ID),
       CaseDescription,
       CaseOwner,
       CaseAssignedTeam,
       ...

FROM Table

GROUP BY CaseDescription,
         CaseOwner,
         CaseAssignedTeam,
         ...

HAVING COUNT(CASE_ID)>1